# AngularJS - Error: Unknown provider: searchResultsProvider

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

**EDIT: I have managed to get my unit tests running - I moved the code containing the services to a different file and a different module, made this new module a requirement for fooBar module, and then before each "it" block is called, introduced the code `beforeEach(module(<new_service_module_name))`. However, my application still won't run. No errors in console either. This is the only issue that remains - that when I use global scope for controllers definition, the application works, but when I use angular.module.controller - it does not.**

I have a file `app.js` that contains the following:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('fooBar', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/form-view.html',
    controller: FormViewCtrl
  }).
  when('/resultDisplay', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/table-view.html',
    controller: TableViewCtrl
  }).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

app.service('searchResults', function() {
  var results = {};

  return {
    getResults: function() {
      return results;
    },
    setResults: function(resultData) {
      results = resultData;
    }
  };
});
```

I have another file `controllers.js` that contains the following:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('fooBar', []);

app.controller('FormViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'searchResults', 
    function ($scope, $location, $http, searchResults) {
        //Controller code
}]);
```

`searchResults` is a service that I created that simply has getter and setter methods. The controller above uses the setter method, hence the service is injected into it.

As a result, my application just does not run! **If I change the controller code to be global like this:**

```
function ($scope, $location, $http, searchResults) {
    //Controller code
}
```

**then the application works!**

Also, if I use the global scope, then the following unit test case works:

```
'use strict';

/*jasmine specs for controllers go here*/
describe('Foo Bar', function() {

    describe('FormViewCtrl', function() {
        var scope, ctrl;

        beforeEach(module('fooBar'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('FormViewCtrl', {$scope: scope});
        }));
        }
        //"it" blocks
}
```

If I revert to the module scope, I get the error -
`Error: Unknown provider: searchResultsProvider <- searchResults`

Thus, by using global scope my application and unit tests run but by using app.controller, they seem to break.

Another point that I have noted is that if I include the controller code in `app.js` instead of `controllers.js`, then the application and unit tests start working again. But I cannot include them in the same file - how do I get this to run in the angular scope without breaking the application and unit tests?

Comment: Rather than make an edit you should have created a new answer and marked it correct!

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to go that route. You can use the modular approach, but the issue is with your second parameter.

In your app.js you have this:

```
var app = angular.module('fooBar', []);
```

Then in your controller, you have this:

```
var app = angular.module('fooBar', []);
```

What you're doing there is defining the module twice. If you're simply trying to attach to the app module, you cannot pass in the second parameter (the empty array: `[]`), as this creates a brand new module, overwriting the first.

Here is how I do it (based on [this article](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html) for architecting large AngularJS apps.

app.js:

```
angular.module('fooBar',['fooBar.controllers', 'fooBar.services']);
angular.module('fooBar.controllers',[]);
angular.module('fooBar.services', []);
...etc
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('foobar.controllers') // notice the lack of second parameter
    .controller('FormViewCtrl', function($scope) {
        //controller stuffs
    });
```

Or, for very large projects, the recommendation is NOT to group your top-level modules by type (directives, filters, services, controllers), but instead by features (including all of your partials... the reason for this is total modularity - you can create a new module, with the same name, new partials & code, drop it in to your project as a replacement, and it will simiply work), e.g.

app.js

```
angular.module('fooBar',['fooBar.formView', 'fooBar.otherView']);
angular.module('fooBar.formView',[]);
angular.module('fooBar.otherView', []);
...etc
```

and then in a `formView` folder hanging off web root, you THEN separate out your files based on type, such as:

```
formView.directives
formView.controllers
formView.services
formView.filters

And then, in each of those files, you open with: 

angular.module('formView')
    .controller('formViewCtrl', function($scope) {

angular.module('formView')
    .factory('Service', function() {

etc etc
```

HTH

Comment: Thankyou.. This solved my problem. I found nowhere in the docs that you cannot define application dependencies twice.  It was redefining my main module as you stated. Changing that solved this error for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I finally figured it out. Basically, if you wish to use the module scope and not the global scope, then we need to do the following (if you have a setup like `app.js` and `controllers.js`):

1. In app.js, define the module scope:

   `var myApp = angular.module(<module_name>, [<dependencies>]);`
2. In controllers.js, do not define myApp again - instead, use it directly like:

   `myApp.controller(..);`

That did the trick - my application and unit tests are now working correctly!

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to have only one global variable, your app and attach all the needed module functionality to that so your app is initiated with

```
var app = angular.module('app',[ /* Dependencies */ ]);
```

in your controller.js you have initiated it again into a new variable, losing all the services and config you had attached to it before, only initiate your app variable once, doing it again is making you lose the service you attached to it

and then to add a service (Factory version)

```
app.factory('NewLogic',[ /* Dependencies */ , function(  /* Dependencies */ ) {
return {
function1: function(){
   /* function1 code */

    }
  }
}]);
```

for a controller

```
app.controller('NewController',[ '$scope' /* Dependencies */ , function( $scope /* Dependencies */ ) {
$scope.function1 = function(){
   /* function1 code */
    };
  }
}]);
```

and for directives and config is similar too where you create your one app module and attach all the needed controllers, directives and services to it but all contained within the parent app module variable.

I have read time and time again that for javascript it is best practice to only ever have one global variable so angularjs architecture really fills that requirement nicely,

Oh and the array wrapper for dependencies is not actually needed but will create a mess of global variables and break app completely if you want to minify your JS so good idea to always stick to the best practice and not do work arounds to get thing to work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've defined a new provider, say, `xyz`

```
angular.module('test')
.provider('xyz', function () {
    ....
});
```

When you were to config the above provider, you've inject it with '**Provider**' string appended.

Ex:

```
angular.module('App', ['test'])
.config(function (xyzProvider) {
     // do something with xyzProvider....
});
```

If you inject the above provider without the 'Provider' string, you'll get the similar error in OP.